# getMock() undefined in PHPUnit tests with HHVM

Tags: php, phpunit, hhvm

We updated PHPUnit to the latest version yersterday and renamed all calls to `createMock()` from `getMock()`.

Our unit tests pass with PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.0 but fail with HHVM, we get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Gomoob\Pushwoosh\Client\CURLClientTest::createMock() in /home/travis/build/gomoob/php-pushwoosh/src/test/php/Gomoob/Pushwoosh/Client/CURLClientTest.php on line 33
```

You can see the complete build on [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/gomoob/php-pushwoosh/jobs/142600741).

It's very strange because this is a simple [call](https://github.com/gomoob/php-pushwoosh/blob/master/src/test/php/Gomoob/Pushwoosh/Client/CURLClientTest.php#L33) to a protected method declared inside a parent class (see the `createMock()` method [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L1525)).

Do you have any idea why this is failing? Could it be a bug in HHVM?

Comment: my test class usually `extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` can you make a try?

Comment: yes sure, no luck same problem with this class. The new Test case is here https://github.com/gomoob/php-pushwoosh/blob/develop/src/test/php/Gomoob/Pushwoosh/Client/CURLClientTest.php#L19 and failed Travis job here https://travis-ci.org/gomoob/php-pushwoosh/jobs/142799864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `createMock()` method was [introduced in PHPUnit 5.4.0](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L1523). You use an older version on travis - 5.1.3. See https://travis-ci.org/gomoob/php-pushwoosh/jobs/142799864#L910

Your builds for other PHP versions [use PHPUnit 5.4.6](https://travis-ci.org/gomoob/php-pushwoosh/jobs/142799850#L908).

It's probably something you should report to travis. Your other option is to install phpunit via composer as a dev dependency.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jakub Zalas, this was the solution, thanks a lot for your help ! https://travis-ci.org/gomoob/php-pushwoosh/builds/142956447